# Bevel modes in 2.8

Tags: modeling, mesh

Following a simple [tutorial](https://youtu.be/fKff4-nZlAI?t=223), I realized that the bevel was not working properly for me, on the tutorial all the faces are equally big[image]

But when I try to make it similar using the offset mode, it just looks completely wrong[image]

The percent mode is the only one that produces decent results but the outer faces are bigger than the inner ones.[image]
How can I achieve similar results to te tutorial? I tried copying the settings on the bar below but they seem to be a litle different on 2.8.

Thanks in advance

[EDIT] This is what the mesh looks like before aplying any sort of bevel, no duplicated vertices or weird stuff as far as I know[image]

Comment: Offset or width options should work in order to have a regular spacing/shape (with loop slide checked). Are you sure there is nothing to check in the model? The first image seems to indicate irregularities?

Comment: I added an image of how it looks before, I made sure there are no duplicated vertices and even disabled the snap feature. I don´t see an irregularities in the model but I'm very new to this so I don´t know what other things could cause this

Comment: It's not possible to see double vertices (if any) from one screenshot only since they can pretty much overlay other ones and be invisible. That said, select all and remove doubles in Edit mode. Then recalculate normals (since in 2.8 inverted ones aren't visible in default shading) Then make sure object scale is even (Object mode, Ctrl+A, scale)

Comment: It worked!! It was the scale that was wrong, I did as Mr Zak said and it worked like a charm. Thank you all very much :)